# How can I interface an ARM chip with an external memory chip?

Tags: memory, arm, microcontroller

I have finished a project using an LPC2132 and quickly ran into problems with not having enough RAM (64k).

For my next project, I'd like to avoid this problem all together by picking a chip that can interface with an external, larger memory chip. How can I do this or where are some resources that I could read up on this at? (I already did Google for about an hour)

Comment: Why is this being downvoted and voted to close as off-topic? I'm asking for a programming solution to interface with an external memory chip. This is very much programming related.

Comment: It would appear to be a hardware-related question rather than a programming-rlated question - you're asking about interfacing memory chips to ARM micro-controllers, right ? Maybe try chiphackers.com ?

Comment: Oh man, chip hacker is just what I was looking for! I'd give you an answer if you posted that.

Answer (score 2):

Since this has no EMIF (External Memory Interface), you're kind of out of luck. The best thing I would suggest is using some SPI RAM (RAM you can interface over a SPI bus). You'll have to do special calls to read/write to it, so it won't be as transparent as declaring variables and getting extra RAM, but it's something.